# R: Adding multiple new columns in R

Tags: r

*Edited*

I am creating a new data frame based on existing data.

[image: df1]

[image]

Right now, this is what I am doing (I know this is crude and naive):

```
df2$Month_Start_Date <- df1$Month_Start_Date
df2$Month1 <- as.numeric(df1$Active_M1*100/df1$Signed_up)
df2$Month2 <- as.numeric(df1$Active_M2*100/df1$Signed_up)
df2$Month3 <- as.numeric(df1$Active_M3*100/df1$Signed_up) and so on...
```

I have 36 columns in my actual data( in df1) and right now I am repeating the above mentioned calculations for 36 columns to create df2, is there an easier way to have all the 36 columns added in minimum lines of code? Right now I am having 36 lines of code to add 36 columns.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: The code I used to add columns, is that the best way? or is there any other simpler method. Thanks

Comment: "best" in what sense? At a minimum, you need to establish parameters of what that means and, in addition, provide a reproducible example. With the code you're showing the data you provide, it is not possible to create the "new data frame" you're describing as your intended output.

Comment: Thanks Thomas. So, how can I add multiple columns to a data frame?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
df2 <- cbind(df1$Month_Start_Date, df1[, 3:7]/df1$Signed_up)
```

Comment: Thanks Jean!! This is what I wanted! :)